# Is Unity going to end in 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

Please everyone who love Ubuntu Click on the link below and check the article and tell me what going on.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/ubuntu-18-04-ship-gnome-desktop-not-unity

Comment: Okay thanks for the update! I have got some explanations

Comment: @Terrance This isn't an exact duplicate.. they're asking different questions.

Comment: @Seth Doesn't it start with Possible duplicate and not just duplicate.  Plus there are answers in there about Unity ending.

Comment: @Terrance There's a reason the actual close banner says "exact duplicate". The duplicate system is for duplicate *questions*, not answers.

Comment: @Seth So, tell me why [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888987/play-a-random-mp3-file/889003#889003) was closed as a dupe and the question seems different?

Comment: @Seth I am not seeing the wording "exact duplicate" when I choose VTC.

Comment: @Terrance Probably for the same mistaken reason this one is getting close votes ;) Although command-line questions are often more difficult because the only thing that changes are the arguments.

Comment: @Terrance Hmm, looks like they indeed changed the wording. After 5 years I can no longer keep track of everything anymore >.<  my point still stands, however. Two very different questions being asked here.

Comment: @Seth I only chose this one to point OP to that question as there is hope that they can still use Unity.

Comment: @Terrance Plenty of ways to do that without casting a close vote. Most people just say "Related: <url>"

Comment: @Seth I have seen it every both ways.  This is one thing I find very frustrating on this site!

Comment: We can continue this discussion [in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Unity is DISCONTINUED - Nobody has forked Unity 7 yet!

---

Unity will still be available in the repository.  So you could install it if you want until it quit working.

Comment: I did it like that to make it clear.

Comment: you need to @-tag me or I don't see your comment. I edited your answer like that because as-is, IMO, the formatting is obnoxious and unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, the bold is way over the top IMO

Comment: But it made it clear

Comment: @MathCubes Not any more clear than just plain text. It's a short answer, so IMO, you don't need any fancy formatting whatsoever.

Comment: @wjandrea My way of formatting anything is to make the important stuff in.  So people don't need to read the junk if they don't want to.  Like "The" "Is", etc...

Comment: So if it is important more then the other important stuff, it gets even bolder.

Comment: @MathCubes But it's just so short that it doesn't matter. That is, it's three sentences. It takes 10 seconds to read it all.

Comment: @wjandrea that you, but however, if you have problems with reading or reading so much that you can truly no longer comprehension it.  Then it still matters, because I am like that.